# How to update ElementRef in angular 2?

Tags: dom, typescript, angular

I have a issue when using `dynamicComponentloader` to load component. I have a parent component and three kind of subcomponents.

Firstly I drag subcomponent A and subcomponent B into parentcomponent by using **Interact.js**. Displayed like below

```
Component A
Component B
```

The method I use is `loadIntoLocation(.., elementRef, ..)`. Then I change their position by DOM manipulate like this

```
Component B
Component A
```

After changing position I will drag the third component into parentcomponent and I think It should be inserted at the bottom of parentcomponent like below

```
Component B
Component A
Component C
```

But actually the third component is inserted into the location componentA and componentB

```
Component B
Component C
Component A
```

**I have made this example a plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fFZ3tnxa3k2n9dgV6NQL?p=preview)**.

I think what cause this issue is I change the DOM, but not map the change to `elementRef`. So I'm finding a way to update `elementRef` and hope it could solve my issue.

**Any advice to solve this or any solution to change two components' position in angular way?**

Comment: @r2_d2 Thanks for format improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing with this one for a while

First I'm holding the references of the Components being injected so I can use them later

```js
instances : [] = [];

addAB(){
    this.loader.loadIntoLocation(ComponentA, this.elementRef, "container")
      .then((r) => this.instances.push(r));
    this.loader.loadIntoLocation(ComponentB, this.elementRef, "container")
      .then((r) => this.instances.push(r));
}
```

[`loadIntoLocation`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.ts#L261) returns a Promise which resolves to [`ComponentRef`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/dynamic_component_loader.ts#L16), that's what I'm holding into the array.

Now, when we swap both of them, I took the first one, I reinsert it and when it resolves correctly I remove the first reference. To be more clear : *Insert A and B, insert A again, remove the first A*.

```js
changePosition(){
    // Take the first one
    let first = this.instances[0];
    // Reinsert the first one
    this.loader.loadIntoLocation(first.hostComponentType, this.elementRef, "container")
      .then((_) => first.dispose()); // dispose() destroys the previous instance
}
```

And that's all you need. Inserting ComponentC is the same, needs no change. Like I told you in gitter, I think internally it tracks the position and you were manipulating the DOM without angular2 knowing about it (this is pure guessing based on its behavior, obviously requires investigation). So this is the most angular2 way I got, so I hope it helps you.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ira4MlSExmK9Q6VAITdI?p=preview) with your case working.

Comment: This solution works for specially appointed contidion like changing last two subcomponents' position. But if I have four or more subcomponents(A,B,C,D) and want to change B&C's position. It won't work. isn't it?

Comment: The more conditions you have, the more logic. Yes, this answer is specific for the use case you asked about, so if it is there more behind the question you'll have to work a little bit more the logic, but you already gave a step forward, now you have something to work with :D

Comment: Sure. You already give me a direction and I will continue to work on this. Your answer gave me much information about ng2 and I even dont know _loadIntoLocation_ can return a promise XD. Maybe I should do more research about source code due to the uncomplete doc.

Comment: Seems there has a problem by this approach. I must use configuration within instance in this use case. But when you dispose the previous instance, i will lost all information in it.

Comment: I have solved this by replacing config like `_.instance.config = this.instances[0].instance.config` in the promise in changePosition method:)